# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

Tags: android, gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
 com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    3

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.outputBlock(RopTranslator.java:253)
        at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.outputInstructions(RopTranslator.java:233)
        at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.translateAndGetResult(RopTranslator.java:212)
        at com.android.dx.dex.code.RopTranslator.translate(RopTranslator.java:105)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:317)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.googleplus_1"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
}
/*
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}*/
```

Comment: You don't have enough Java heap space. Have you changed the VM settings?

Comment: No I did not change.
For some reason now I am getting a diff error msg.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
 C:\Users\bhurata\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\maindexlist.txt --output C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\___\android\GooglePlus_1\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
 3

Comment: I have no idea, sorry...

Comment: I figure out that adding this:
        compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
is causing the issue. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you adding `com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1`?

If you read on it's official site: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/, it says:

> **Android support:** If you are developing for Android and the Google API you want to use is included in the Google Play Services library,
>   you should use that library for the best performance and experience.
>   If the Google API you want to use with Android is not part of the
>   Google Play Services library, you can use the [Google APIs Client
>   Library for Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), which supports Android 1.5 (or higher) and provides
>   other features such as OAuth 2.0 and Maven.

It suggests you use:

```
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
  }
```

Very important for **Google Play Services**, **do not** use the "whole" dependency directly:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```

**Do** pick individual **modules** that you need:

```
dependencies {
    # Google+
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0
    # Google Account Login
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0
    # Google Actions, Base Client Library
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
    # Google App Indexing
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.0.0
    # Google Analytics
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0
    # Google Cast
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.0.0
    # Google Cloud Messaging
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0
    # Google Drive
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.0.0
    # Google Fit
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.0.0
    # Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0
    # Google Maps
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0
    # Google Mobile Ads
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0
    # Google Nearby
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.0.0
    # Google Panorama Viewer
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.0.0
    # Google Play Game services
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.0.0
    # SafetyNet
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.0.0
    # Google Wallet
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.0.0
    # Android Wear
    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.0.0
}
```

**Source:** http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Jared, many thanks for answer. I will answer your question:
"Why are you adding com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1?" : I am using this to access Albums from PIcasa (Google+).

Also, the error went away when I included the individual modules.

Comment: @GreenApple Good! I believe that the library was so large, it was taking up a lot your computer's memory.